# pointer from glMapBufferARB used in another context

Tags: opengl, rendering, gpu

I want to do parallel rendering with 2 GPUs. So a readback from GPU1 and then  drawing pixels to GPU2 are needed.

I created two windows in each screen with its own GPU connected. And there are two threads associated to each window.

However, the readpixel+drawpixel is a bottleneck.  So a async PBO method is considered: 2 PBOs for reading back and 2 PBOs for drawing back in alternative way.

My question is:

1. Could Pointer returned from glMapBufferARB be used in another thread and different GPU?
2. If not, I must copy data to main memory and copy it to another GPU, the bottleneck will be CPU->GPU copying. Is there any better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, pointer form glMapBuffer can be used by any thread - even without GL context. Just remember to synchronize threads and don't call glUnmapBuffer before thread finishes its job with pointer.h